# Declaring Collections in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I wasn't sure how to search for an answer to this.

What is the difference between the following declarations?

```
    List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I sometimes see the first declaration being used but as ArrayList inherits methods from it's superinterfaces and superclasses, I'm not sure why that is used. Would someone be able to clarify? Thanks!

Comment: Because tomorrow someone will want to change it to a `LinkedList` or a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or a `MagicFairyList`.

Comment: It is polimorphism. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not be dependent on implementation of interface. If you use `List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();` - you'll be able to change implementation easily, without affecting all other code, because you're using only methods, defined in `List` interface.

Using `ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();`, you become bound to one implementation of interface, and your class becomes coupled much more tightly to implementation, which usually must be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

The first declaration uses the interface as refrence type, which is more portable but doesn't provide access to ArrayList specific methods. It provides you the possibility to change your implementation of the List without affecting other parts of your application.

The second defines the class as refrence type. All code that relies on this reference type will need to be changed when you change it.

Tip: Also if you are using Java SE 7 or later you can ommit the generic type in the construction part:

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

When one uses:

```
        List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

It offers more flexibility, in OOP terms- it exploits the feature of Polymorphism. List is an interface, ArrayList, LinkedList etc are its different implementations. In one's program if, a1 is declared as above then tomorrow for some reason if instead of an ArrayList, one decides to use some other List implementation, one would just need to make the following change:

```
       List<Integer> al = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Wherever a1 is used needn't change, unlike the latter declaration.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The difference is not much *at this specific kind of code*, but to the following code using `al`, the difference is whether the code can rely on the interface defined in `List` or the interface defined by the class `ArrayList`, which opens up more implementation details.

Furthermore, a practical example is when you don't construct `al` by yourself but rather let a method construct it, such that the method creator has to decide whether the return type is of a concrete type or of an interface type and how tight his implementation of the method is bound to the users of the method.

Example:

```
public ArrayList<String> createArrayList() {
    return new ArrayList<String>(); // is bound to the return type and a change my break code relying on the methods contract
}

public List<String> createList() {
    return new ArrayList<String>(); // can be changed to any other List implementation as the code relying on the method contract can only assume implementations of List
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read about 'Runtime Polymorphism' and 'Dynamic Method Dispatch' in Java. For your help.... [try this link](http://www.studytonight.com/java/dynamic-method-dispatch)